# Encrypting a ROT13 Program in Java

Tags: java, encryption, rot13

I have a question regarding my Rot13 program in Java. First of all, here´s my code:

```
import java.io.*;


public class Rot13 {

public static main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter a phase:");
    String input = myInput.readLine();

    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
            char lowerChar = (char) (Character.toLowerCase(c) - 97);
            lowerChar += 13;
            lowerChar %= 26;
            lowerChar += 97;
            System.out.print(Character.isUpperCase(c) ? Character.toUpperCase(lowerChar) : lowerChar);
        } else {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }

    myInput.close();
}
}
```

Now, the program works perfectly fine, but I was asking myself, if the program would look better if I'd use the Encrypt in the program. Other people from my University were also saying, that using encrypt in this type of program (Rot13) would be much better then what I'm using right now.

If it's better to use Encrypt in this program, where should I do in order to change my program?

Comment: I think they mean to say to use the framework which already exists in Java to create an extension that supports this ROT13.  The actual encryption part is done.  You need only understand how to register your class so you can call it like `MessageDigest.getInstance("ROT13")` and use it as you would any `MessageDigest` instance.  I won't do this for you since it seems to be part of your assignment.  Found a good resource about this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#CipherBased).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). - For comments on working code https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the appropriate site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it rather belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/